# I am trying to update (new version) my app on iTunes connect. After uploading, the apple developers rejected my binary with the reason :-

Tags: ios

The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “MyCP￼” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the MyConnaughtPlace￼ brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the Contact Us page.

Best regards,

App Store Review

Answer (score 0):

Just change your app name to a new name that reflects the MyConnaughtPlace￼ brand.

I also met this before.